# .ebextensions not included in AWS source bundle

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a .net core application which was earlier hosted on aws with ssl and load balancer. But in order to avoid load balancer I found that ssl will also not work without load balancer. As an alternative for SSL certificate I created a folder in root folder - .ebextensions and a config file inside it.

[image]

The problem is when I am publishing it to aws via elasticbeanstalk then the .ebextensions is not included in the source bundle and therefore ssl certificate is not working. Is there any way I can include this folder or any alternative way to get ssl certificate without load balancer. Please advice.

Comment: ebextensions should be kept in the same directory as your dockerrun.aws.json files etc.

Comment: Do you have any .gitignore or something simliar which would ignore the folder?

Comment: Yeah I forgot that point as @Marcin said elasticbeanstalk ignores the files in .gitignore

Comment: no, i checked and there is no such file, text or folder

Comment: Where is your .ebextensions directory? can you elaborate?

Comment: As shown in the screenshot it is directly under the project folder. Also I have a similar copy under wwwroot folder

Comment: Now I am trying a different technique for ssl and ie via cloudfront. Do CloudFront alone will setup SSL or I also need LoadBalancer for this? In short my purpose is to install SSL withot Loadbalancer

Comment: CloudFront does not solve much. You will still have HTTP between CloudFront and your EB. You have to install SSL on your EB instance for proper https.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin I added ebextensions successfully by enabling the http-instnace..config file content enabled for copying. But now after publishing to the aws, the health of application degraded. I have just followed the steps mentioned in this article as suggested by you https://www.tutcodex.com/ssl-on-single-instance-elastic-beanstalk-tutorial/

Comment: This seems to be new issue, so you can make new SO question. So what was the issue with `.ebextensions` folder?

Comment: Just posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very small thing which I ignored. Just change the Build Action of config file from None to Content will allow the folder and file to be copied. Empty folder not included while publishing. Thanks @Marcin and @Sridhar Raju for all the help

[image]